# Image height inside flexbox not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, responsive-images

I have a `div` using **flexbox** to center its items. Inside this `div` I have 3 elements, one of them is an image.

```
<div id="flex-container">
    <div id="container1"></div>
    <img src="#" alt="">
    <div id="container2"></div>
</div>
```

`#container1` and `#container2` have their own height, and the `img` should use the remaining height inside `#flex-container`.

This snippet **works on Firefox**, but **doesn't work in Chrome**. ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsbLjrzp/7/))

```css
#flex-container{
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#container1, #container2{
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">

  <div id="container1">300x100 px</div>

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" alt="">

  <div id="container2">300x100 px</div>

</div>
```

<s>Chrome needs `-webkit-` prefixes for flexbox, but the issue doesn't seem to be this.</s>

What can be happening? Is a browser bug or I'm forgetting something?

Comment: Should they flow from left to right or top to bottom?

Comment: @LGSon from top to bottom, with items centered in the `flex-container`.

Comment: Btw, you don't need prefixes to run flexbox in Chrome. http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: @Michael_B Nice to know it, I used this one [shouldiprefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox). Now I see Chrome is supported, but others like safari still need prefixes :(

Comment: Here's a full review of browser support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems you need to overcome:

Firefox solves them both on its own, but Chrome needs assistance.

### Problem #1

The first problem is that flex items, by default, cannot be smaller than their content. An initial setting on flex items is `min-height: auto`.

Therefore, a flex item with a replaced element, like an image, will default to the inherent size of the image. The item cannot be made smaller, unless you override the initial setting (use `min-height: 0`).

```css
#flex-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
#container1, #container2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
img { min-height: 0; } /* NEW */
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">

  <div id="container1">300x100 px</div>

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" alt="">

  <div id="container2">300x100 px</div>

</div>
```

A complete explanation of this issue can be found here:

- **[Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)**

---

### Problem #2

Then you hit the second problem: keeping the aspect ratio. This is a common problem in flex containers. One option is to define a height for the image:

```css
#flex-container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
#container1, #container2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
img { min-height: 0; height: 100px; } /* NEW */
```

```html
<div id="flex-container">

  <div id="container1">300x100 px</div>

  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RRUe0Mo.png" alt="">

  <div id="container2">300x100 px</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I'm still not understanding exactly why the `min-height` is necessary to make it work on Chrome, but it's extensively explained on your answers, I will take another look when I can. And there is no way to shrink the image height at the same time as keeping the aspect ratio? Wrapping it inside a `div` maybe?

Comment: Yes, my linked answer provides a detailed explanation. About the aspect ratio, like I said, it's a common problem and I've seen many solutions. A `div` wrapper has worked for me before. Test it out. Cheers!

Comment: To whom it may concern: shrinking image while maintaining aspect ratio can be done with `object-fit: contain;` CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @alexandr in the comments, this was the perfect solution for me:

```
object-fit: contain; // done on the image resizes the height
```

I'm just putting it in here because it is a proper answer that may be missed as a comment.